# renaming files with a shell script

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have a lot of files following are the files

```
DSCN2352.JPG  DSCN2356.JPG  DSCN2360.JPG  DSCN2364.JPG
DSCN2353.JPG  DSCN2357.JPG  DSCN2361.JPG  DSCN2365.JPG
```

I want to rename these files so I wrote a script

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a kl=( "$@" )
kl=$(ls *.JPG)
echo ${kl[@]}
p=0
for i in kl ;
 do mv $kl d$p.JPG
  $p=$p+1  ;
 done
```

I am getting error

```
mv: target `d0.JPG' is not a directory
./rename.sh: line 8: 0=0+1: command not found
```

**UPDATE**
after updating the script

```
#/bin/bash
p=0
for i in *.JPG;
do
mv "$i" "d$p.JPG"
(( p+1 ))  ;
done
```

files

```
DSCN2352.JPG  DSCN2356.JPG  DSCN2360.JPG  DSCN2364.JPG
DSCN2353.JPG  DSCN2357.JPG  DSCN2361.JPG  DSCN2365.JPG
```

disappear and 
 I am left with only one file
d0.jpg  rest of the files get deleted after executing updated script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```sh
$p=$p+1  ;
```

to

```sh
(( p=p+1 ))
```

or simply

```sh
(( p++ ))
```

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
p=0
for i in *.JPG
do
  mv "$i" d$p.JPG
  p=$(($p+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
p=0
for file in ./*.JPG ; do
    echo "$file"
    mv $file d$p.JPG
    p=`expr $p + 1`
done
```